# Проверить домен на cross-origin policy

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, cross-origin

- *`Можете читать по выделенному тексту`*
- У меня есть **iframe**,  в который загружается **произвольный**, выбранный пользователем **сайт** *(напр. google.com или yandex.ru)*.
- **Проблема** в том, что в некоторых случаях, когда на сервере другого сайта включена **блокировка iframe** (cross origin policy), **событие ошибки**  *onerror*  **не срабатывает** . **В таком случае** мне **нужно** просто **перенаправить пользователя на сайт** в iframe.
- Вопрос: **как "отловить" ошибку**

> **P.S.**

- Если невозможно на JavaScript, то **можно ли** на **php**?

Comment: Проверил несколько вариантов, найденных в интернете. Они были 5+ летней давности. Действительно, сейчас ситуация не изменилась, и нельзя проверить CORS в браузере нативными средствами. Но можно сделать проверку на сервере. Как это сделать, [подробно описано тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30004160/9435985)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал товарищ [**Total Pusher**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/287469/total-pusher), узнать **COP** (*Cross Origin Policy*) *невозможно на стороне клиента*, но возможно на стороне сервера(*напр.* **PHP**).

> Можно сделать проверку на сервере. Как это сделать, [Подробно описано тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30004160/9435985).